Questions About My Perpetual Motion Idea
Before you read any of this, this is just an idea. I am not an electrician, I am not a contractor, I am not a physicist, or anything like that. I just have an idea that i think could possibly work. I know people are going to comment on this post that perpetual motion is impossible, and I understand that. I just don't see a reason why this shouldn't work. Of course, the purpose of the post is for someone who knows more than me to point out what causes this to not work.
With that being said, here is what I know. One day, I came across this Youtube video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZwEwfpSf8Ho
After seeing that i got curious on if this was real or not. After doing research and watching this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-vaD24Y3L5I
I realized instantly that it was fake.
So, in the video, he mentioned that energy loss was the main issue with this idea. In summary, if you feed 100 watts into a motor with an 80% efficiency rating, only about 80 watts of energy will come out of it, this is the same with the alternator. After time, all power in the loop would be lost. This is a 3D model that i rigged up in a couple minutes of that system.


So, you may ask, how do i plan to fix that issue? Well, I don't know if this sounds dumb to any electricians, but my idea is to just add another alternator in the loop. Like this:


In my head, this would completely fix the issue. With 2 alternators, 2x the power is put out. If a motor has an 80% efficiency rating (along with both alternators), if 100 watts is given to the motor, on the first rotation, 128 watts would be put out. (((100 x 0.80) x 0.80) x 2)
Now that you have all this information, please let me know if this has a chance of working. And, if it doesn't, please explain why. Thank you for your time, and I hope somebody can help me out with this.

The load on the motor would double.

You've now doubled your motor losses to 40w.

The power supplied by the generator must drive all of the load.  You cannit get something for nothing.

I’m voting to close this post because it's yet another daft perpetual motion question with no effort at research and zero evidence of compliance with the laws of physics.

In the post I quite literately specified "This is just an idea. I am not an electrician, I am not a contractor, I am not a physicist, or anything like that. I just have an idea that i think could possibly work." And I cant find anything on the internet where people use 2 alternators instead of 1.

Let's say each of the two alternators produces 40 watts, for 80 watts electrical output in total. Each alternator takes 50 watts to drive (80% efficiency) for a total of 100 watts mechanical in via the belt. That's the same as a single 80% efficient alternator taking 100 watts mechanical to output 80 watts electrical. Your idea is simply a variation on the 'let's throw more 'stuff' at the problem, and hope the conservation laws don't notice.' Nope, that doesn't work. Every motor and alternator is a 'transformer' between electrical and mechanical energy, with a less than unity efficiency.

The alternator gets harder to spin the more load there is on it (on top of the inevitable friction losses even if there is no load).
Two alternators mean twice the mechanical load on the motor. It’s basically no better than a single bigger alternator.

How much force does an alternator take to push? In my mind, they are virtually weightless.

@DylDev They take as much energy to turn as the load takes out of them times the efficiency. Any idea you have for a perpetual motion machine will not work, period.

If you try using a stationary exercise bike that has no external power source and displays the number of watts you are generating you will get a ‘feel’ for how much work it is to output 50 or 100W. Far from effortless. One benefit of understanding laws like conservation of energy and where exactly they apply is that it saves us time in going down dead ends like this one.

P.S. if the alternator magically had zero losses (no bearing friction, internal electrical resistance, air resistance etc.) the torque in N-m would be P*(60/2π)* (1/RPM). So if the alternator is turning at 1000 RPM and the output power is 100W the torque will be about 1 N-m. Of course in reality it will be at least somewhat more because of losses. What you can get from this is that ideally torque is proportional to output power (for fixed RPM) and inversely proportional to RPM (for fixed power). Think of the linear: force = work done/distance and add the time element, power = work/unit time.
